# Member "swapExactTokensForTokens" not found or not visible - Solidity trading bot

Tags: solidity, uniswap, python, brownie, sushiswap

I've been working on a arbitrage solidity bot on Uni- and SushiSwap and I have a strange error:

```
TypeError: Member "swapExactTokensForTokens" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract ISushiswapRouter.
  --> contracts/ArbitrageBot.sol:35:13:
   |
35 |             ISushiswapRouter(sushiswapRouter).swapExactTokensForTokens(
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here is the smart contract code snippet:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";


interface IUniswapV2Router {
    function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}

interface ISushiswapRouter {
    function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}

contract ArbitrageBot {
    address public constant uniswapRouter = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;
    address public constant sushiswapRouter = 0x1b02dA8Cb0d097eB8D57A175b88c7D8b47997506;

    function arb() external {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(0x11fE4B6AE13d2a6055C8D9cF65c55bac32B5d844); // DAI
        path[1] = address(0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6); // WETH

        uint uniswapAmount = IUniswapV2Router(uniswapRouter).getAmountsOut(1000, path)[1];
        uint sushiswapAmount = ISushiswapRouter(sushiswapRouter).getAmountsOut(1000, path)[1];

        if (uniswapAmount > sushiswapAmount) {
            // Buy on Sushiswap, Sell on Uniswap
            uint256 amountIn = 1000;
            uint256 amountOutMin = sushiswapAmount;

            IERC20(path[0]).approve(sushiswapRouter, amountIn);

            ISushiswapRouter(sushiswapRouter).swapExactTokensForTokens(
                amountIn,
                amountOutMin,
                path,
                address(this),
                block.timestamp
            );

            IUniswapV2Router(uniswapRouter).swapTokensForExactTokens(
                amountOutMin,
                uniswapAmount,
                path,
                msg.sender,
                block.timestamp
            );
...
```

The contract addresses should be right, but I am not sure what causes the error and would be very grateful for your support, thanks!
PS: The error appears when I try to compile the contract via brownie and I am currently working on goerli I am not using mainnet addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring the `ISushiSwapRouter` interface wrong. You only declared getAmountsOut, just add the definition of `swapExactTokensForTokens` in there. (and in IUniswapV2Router too, since you're using it right after (you don't really need 2 different interfaces there, btw))

Something like :

```
interface ISwapRouter {
    function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);

    function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);


}

contract ArbitrageBot { 
    address public constant uniswapRouter = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;
    address public constant sushiswapRouter = 0x1b02dA8Cb0d097eB8D57A175b88c7D8b47997506;
    // ... 
    // And then ISwapRouter(routerAddress).function(params) to use the interface, works for both contracts since they have the same functions. 

}
```